# bash printf formatting - avoid long lines wrapping

Tags: bash, printf

input sample:

```
line1:word word
line2:word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word
line3:word word word
```

When I format it with printf, the loner line is wrapped - how to avoid it?

```
$ cat input_test|while IFS=: read a b;do printf "%-10s %-3s %s\n" "$a" ":" "$b";done
line1      :   word word
line2      :   word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
word word word word word word word word word
line3      :   word word word
```

If second column (delimited by colon) is longer than possible number of characters in line in a terminal expected output is:

```
line1      :   word word
line2      :   word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
               word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
               word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
               word word word
line3      :   word word word
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [column](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/column.1.html):

```
cat input_test | column -c100 -s: -o'      :   ' -t -W2
```

Sadly this will output additional ':' in output:

```
line1      :   word word
line2      :   word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
           :   word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
           :   word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
           :   word word word
line3      :   word word word
```

We can remove them with `sed`:

```
cat input_test | column -c100 -s: -o'      :   ' -t -W2 | sed 's/^           :   /               /'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with `awk` here then following may help you, also not sure your 2nd line's after splitting it you always need 3 columns there? following will not do that.

```
awk -v s1="\t" '{sub(/:/,"      :     ",$1)}NF>10{;for(i=10;i<=NF;i+=10){$i=$i ORS s1 s1}} 1' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
line1      :     word word
line2      :     word word word word word word word word word word
                 word word word word word word word word word word
                 word word word word word word word word word word
                 word word word word word word word word word word
                 word word word word word word word word word word
                 word word word word
line3      :     word word word
```

You could change `NF>10` as per your need too here as per number of columns too. If you are changing it then please change for loop's digits(wherever it is 10) to that number too.